# Difference between Profile & Sharing Settings?

Tags: profile, permissions, role-hierarchy

We have a flat organizational `Role Hierarchy`. One Manager (Profile 1) and two Staff (Profile 2) for both South and West. Both of these managers report up to the Regional Manager.

We have built loads of custom objects in our org but I have been told that one of Profile 2 staff in the hierarchy can run reports showing sensitive information from the regional manager?

Would this be a Profile update to ensure they cannot see that field or do I need to adjust the Sharing setting for the custom object

Comment: Hi Vince, welcome to SFSE! I didn't down-vote you and I'm not sure why the person who did, did so. But please take a moment to visit  the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Proper tagging can really help the community understand your problem and also find it later. I've re-tagged your post based on its content.

Comment: Hello Adrian, Sorry if i posted in the wrong area but i will take time to take the tour. Thank you for re-tagging my question, I do appreciate that. Thank you again, Vince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiles affect what people can do, while sharing settings affect what people can see and edit. For example, if you wanted to make it so users could not edit any records, you would give them the Read Only profile, but if you wanted them to edit some records, you'd configure your sharing settings so that users can only edit accounts they own or that are shared with them. In your case, the most appropriate action would be to configure your sharing settings.